# Get recurrence of different MySQL records

Tags: mysql, recurrence

I want to get the text back the most times.

Example1:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3  Column4  Column5
Red      Red     Red       White    Blank
```

Result Query:

```
Red
```

Example2:

```
Colum1 Colum2  Colum3  Colum4  Colum5
White  White   Red     Yellow  Blank
```

Result Query:

```
White
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently came across something similar to this problem. Hope this helps.

```
select col
from
(select col1 as col from tab1
 union all
 select col2 as col from tab1
 union all
 select col3 as col from tab1
 union all
 select col4 as col from tab1
 union all
 select col5 as col from tab1) as new_table
group by col order by count(*) desc limit 1;
```